# Remotely send current website to another browser on network

Tags: remote-control

I have a number of non-technical trainers who use their browsers to run training sessions. They need to quickly send their current website to a number of browsers within a local area network - this is the only type of control that the facilitator needs over the trainees computers.

Is there a way to quickly send the URL of my current website to another browser?

I am hoping for something similiar to Google Chrome's "Chrome to Phone" (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-chrome-to-phone-ex/) but instead we're sending the URL to another Chrome instance, rather than a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension [Xmarks Bookmark Sync](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xmarks-bookmark-sync/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla) from the Chrome Web Store will do it.

It is mainly for syncing bookmarks, but it will also work for tab syncing.